# Dualboot: Ubuntu/Win10 - Grub can't boot Win10

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, boot, grub

I have a Windows 10 boot problem. I choose windows boot manager from grub menu. System try to fix it self and can't boot.

Ubuntu works fine. and I can see windows disk etc.

My theory is I have two windows boot manager but I am not sure. The reason is I have two of them;

```
$ sudo blkid

/dev/sda1: PARTLABEL="Microsoft reserved partition"
/dev/nvme0n1p2: PARTLABEL="Microsoft reserved partition"
```

maybe that's why I don't know.

as you can see in this image
[grub image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q1k0F.jpg)
there is some options and if I choose windows; windows system repair appear and can't boot.

Comment: As stated previously stated here https://askubuntu.com/questions/1433791/dualboot-ubuntu-win10-grub-cant-boot-win10#comment2498152_1433791 you need to boot Windows installation media and repair it.

Comment: Yes I tried many times startup repairs. But unfortunately also not work.